# Regarding scope in C++ with new operator

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, scope, destructor

If I declare an object in main, then call that class's member function (While inside the function I use the operator new to declare an object of another class), will that nested object still remain in scope after the member function call? in other other words, can I use that object still throughout main? I was going to create a vector of pointers and assign to each position a new object created by the class's function call.

Thankyou in advance! Please let me know if my question is vague.
P.S. If I must define the destructor in the .h file to delete what was created with new, correct? This is not automatically done by the compiler?

```
int main()
{
  Ship *list[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  char ch;
  int x1,y1,x2,y2;
  int n = 0;

  cin >> ch >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
  while ( cin )
  {
    try
    {
      Ship *p = Ship::makeShip(ch,x1,y1,x2,y2);
      list[n++] = p;
    }
```

In my program, makeShip returns a pointer to a new Ship Object. How come I can use the Ship object throughout my main()? I thought it goes out of scope after the second } ending brace for try? Thanks!!

Comment: You could make your question a lot less vague by showing some code

Comment: To make it simple new allocate memory so if you don't lost the address you can use the object from anywhere in your program until you delete it or lost it (memory leak)

Comment: To have Ship destructor called, you have to use smart pointer, something like `std::unique_ptr<Ship> list[5];`

Comment: @TonyD Sorry I read `cout`

Answer (score 1):

Anything created with `new` remains live untill you destroy it with a `delete`. So object remains in scope and as long as you have a reference to refer the object, you can access it.

Only `automatic` variables go out of scope after the `}`. In your case you can access `Ship` objects via `list`.

Although I would recommend `std::array<Ship>` or `std::vector<Ship>` instead of `Ship *[]`

**EDIT**
After your question is edited and some code section is added, whether scope of `Ship` objects would end after `}` or not depends on what and how does `Ship::makeShip` return.

Comment: I guess that answers my question! Also, the object isn't automatically destroyed even if i just have ~destructor inside my class right? I need to write a delete code?

Comment: Thankyou very much! I appreciate it. So does your answer apply to my question? If i call new inside a function within main, that new object has global scope?

Comment: Yes, the objects have global scope. Make sure you delete all Ships at end. `for(int i = 4; i >= 0; --i) {delete list[i]; list[i] = 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

In this case it depends on implementation of `Ship::makeShip`.

1. If `makeShip` stores pointer into some storage (for example `static std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` pointers) then memory will be cleared after exit from program.
   In this case you do not need to delete `list` manually, because you have only references.
2. `Ship::makeShip` returns a pointer which you need to delete manually. In this case for all list items `delete` operator should be called.

And the last one,

It is bad practice to return raw pointers, it is really unclear how deal with it, when to delete, who owns and so on.

It will be better to return for example `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

In the first case it is clear that you becomes an owner of the pointer. In the second case it does not matter who owns, because ownership is shared

Comment: I'm not that advanced into C++ yet but thanks. Can you elaborate on what you said for #1? I basically understood from this post that anything created with New will have global scope until the end of the program or until delete operator is called on it?

Comment: if you are using new operator then memory can be relуased only buy calling delete operator or when the module dies(exit from exe-file or unloading dll library)